# how to get a json value to array adapter

Tags: android, json, picasso

I need help please , I have got `name` from php, how to send it to array adapter?

```
protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
        String name;
        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


            ImageListAdapter itemsAdapter = 
                    new ImageListAdapter(MainActivity.this, name);
```

I am having problem in this `ImageListAdapter` constructer.

```
  public ImageListAdapter(Context context, String imageUrls) {
        super(context imageUrls);

        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```

how to get name from json to array adapter

```
package com.example.jsn;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private String[] imageUrls;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, String imageUrls) {
        super(context imageUrls);

        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(imageUrls[position])
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // can also be a drawable
            .fit() // will explain later
            .noFade()
            .into((ImageView) convertView);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `imageUrls` is String not `Array` or `List<String>`

Comment: So making it to string[] will solve it ?

Comment: [Read about ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your ImageListAdapter constructor to the following:

```
 public ImageListAdapter (Context context,  String[] urls) {
    super(context, -1, urls);

    this.context = context;
    this.imageUrls = urls;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

So that you are passing an array of String to your adapter. Also, you have to modify your showList() method a little. Try this:

```
protected void showList(){
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
        String[] names = new String[peoples.length()];
        for ( int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++ ) {
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            names[i] = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        }

        ImageListAdapter itemsAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(MainActivity.this, names);



}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The adapter takes its last value as an array. Store the string in an array or Arraylist then place it in the adapter.
Read more about adapters;
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html